# Express "Can't set headers after they are sent" after deploying to Heroku

Tags: express

after deploying my server code to Heroku I'm getting the error "Can't set headers after they are sent". I fetch my login data

```
   fetch("url", {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    //"Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: requestBody
            }).then((res, next) => {
                if(res.ok){
                    res.json().then((json) => {
                        if(json.verifystate){
                            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                        }
                        else{
                          this.setState({isAuthentic:false});
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    next();
                }
            })
```

And it calls my server post method

```
  app.post('/users/auth', function(req, res) {

        loginData(db, req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.mphone, function(result){
          if(result == 1){
            res.send({"verifystate":1});
          }else if(result == 2){
            res.send({"verifystate":2});
          }else{
            res.send({"verifystate":3});
          }
        });
        //console.log('json: '+JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

**edit: Login function**

```
    module.exports = function loginData(db, email, myPlaintextPassword, mphone, callback){

    var collectionUser = db.collection('users');

    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {

        var queryStr = {"emails.address": email};

        collectionUser.findOne(queryStr, function(err, result) {
                if(err)
                {
                    return;
                }else if(result != null){

                    bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, result.services.password.bcrypt, function(err, res) {
                        console.log("conpare result: ", res);
                        if(res){
                            callback("1");
                        }else{
                            callback("3");
                        }

                    });
                    if(!result.services.resume || result.services.resume.appLoginToken == null
                      || !result.services.resume.appLoginToken.date || !result.services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token){

                        var tokenStr = email + Math.random(1,100);
                        tokenStr = Base64.encode(tokenStr);
                        queryStr =  {
                                      "services.resume.appLoginToken.date": Date(),
                                      "services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token": tokenStr
                                    };
                        var newDate =   { "services.resume.appLoginToken.date": Date() }
                        var temp = {"emails.address": email};
                        collectionUser.update(temp,
                          { $set: {"services.resume.appLoginToken.date": Date()} }, function(err, result) {
                        if(err)
                            {
                                return;
                            }else {
                            }
                        });
                        collectionUser.update(temp,
                          { $set: {"services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token": tokenStr} }, function(err, result) {
                        if(err)
                            {
                                return;
                            }else {
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.log("already have token");
                    }
                }else{
                    callback("2")
                }
        });
    });
});
```

};

And when it gets to **res.send({"verifystate:"1})** it then throws the aforementioned error. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: The code you show here will not, by itself, cause the error you are seeing unless `loginData()` somehow calls its callback more than once.  So, if that is not the case, then there must be something else going on that is leading to the problem.  That particular error is nearly always caused by improper asynchronous handling that causes you to attempt to send more than one response to the same request (which is not allowed).  Can you show the code for `loginData()`?

Comment: I'm also guessing that you trimmed some code out of what you posted because `console.log('json: '+JSON.stringify(data));` makes no sense where you have it because there is no `data` variable in what you posted.

Comment: Also, your question references `res.send({"verifystate:"true})`, but there is no such line of code in what you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I changed ({"verifystate":true}) to ({"verifystate":1}) and added the login function, and that `json.stringify(data)` was just a console.log test

Comment: That `loginData()` function really needs to be cleaned up.  There appear to be multiple code paths where you never call the `callback()` which could cause you to never send any response.  There are also several places where you don't handle errors at all.  I don't yet see the smoking gun that caused your original problem, but cleaning up this function to make it bulletproof would be a good place to start.

Comment: But, with the code as you show it, `console.log('json: '+JSON.stringify(data));` will throw an error because there is no `data` variable defined.  It doesn't seem like this is your real code as you are running it.

Comment: Also, your `loginData()` function needs to pass an `err` value to its callback so the caller can see errors and decide what to do based on error conditions.

Comment: Okay, I'll try clean up a lot of the login code, and add the err to the login function. So do you believe that the issue is that the login function is doing multiple callbacks?

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to get multiple calls to the callback function at the moment in `loginData()`.

Comment: I do see some potential race conditions if your client ever makes this ajax call more than once because it calls the callback BEFORE it updates the database.  That means you are returning a response back to the client before you've updated the data which could create a race condition (client expecting database to be updated, but it isn't yet).  That may be either a real or theoretical problem, but it's not a good design to have that vulnerability.  `loginData()` shouldn't call the callback until after it has finished update the database.

Comment: What does `next()` do in the client code and why do you think that `.then()` will get two parameters passed to it in your client code?  That appears wrong on the line where you have `}).then((res, next) => {`.  Per the promise specification, `.then()` handlers only get one parameter passed to them.

Comment: ah jeez you're right, a lot of cleaning up I need to do. Thanks for all the help, I will give it another go!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!res.headersSent){
  res.send('hello world');
}
```

or

```
if(!res.headersSent){
  res.json({message: 'hello world'});
}
```

you probably have a callback that fires more than once, often times this is with event emitters.

As a side note, I really recommend using 2 spaces for indentation with JS, because so much code is nested. And I also recommend putting `else` and `.then()` on a newline, more readable.

Comment: This is a hack to avoid the log message and not a real fix to the problem.  I would avoid ever using fixes like this.  And, I disagree with both formatting suggestions (which is purely a matter of opinion).

Comment: not a hack at all, depending on the use case, and it demonstrates what the problem is => response is being sent more than once. The poster can figure out the rest.

Comment: It's not a fix to the actual logic problem.  Developers that "fix" problems like this are putting a bandaid on a ticking time bomb.  The real logic problem should be found and fixed because there also could easily be other issues caused by the logic problem.

Comment: Yes I agree that the real logic problem should be fixed by the OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the whole code but you could try this:

module.exports = function loginData(db, email, myPlaintextPassword, mphone, callback) {

```
let collectionUser = db.collection('users');

bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function (err, hash) {

        let queryStr = {"emails.address": email};

        collectionUser.findOne(queryStr, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                //You should do something here or it would take you to an error , just an return won't work, you've to call a callback that send the error message 
                //callback(0)
            } else if (result !== null) {

                if (!result.services.resume || result.services.resume.appLoginToken === null
                    || !result.services.resume.appLoginToken.date || !result.services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token) {

                    let tokenStr = email + Math.random(1, 100), temp = {"emails.address": email};
                    tokenStr = Base64.encode(tokenStr);
                    queryStr = {
                        "services.resume.appLoginToken.date": new Date(),
                        "services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token": tokenStr
                    };
                    collectionUser.update(temp,
                        {$set: {"services.resume.appLoginToken.date": new Date()}}, function (err, result) {
                        });
                    collectionUser.update(temp,
                        {$set: {"services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token": tokenStr}}, function (err, result) {
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log("already have token");
                }
                bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, result.services.password.bcrypt, function (err, res) {
                    console.log("conpare result: ", res);
                    if (res) {
                        callback(1);
                    } else {
                        callback(3);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                callback(2);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

};

And this:

```
app.post('/users/auth', function (req, res) {
    loginData(db, req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.mphone, function (result) {
        res.send({verifystate: result});
    });
});
```